# checking in the model for nulls

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I like to check the model for nulls before I use the value in the view. Is this the correct way to use the `get` and `set`? I am getting an Exception of type `'System.StackOverflowException' was thrown."` on the `this.MiddleInitial = value;`

Model

```cs
public string MiddleInitial {
    get {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(MiddleInitial) == true) {
            return MiddleInitial;

        }
        return $ "{MiddleInitial.Trim()}.";

    }
    set {
        this.MiddleInitial = value;
    }
}
```

Updated Model

```cs
public string MiddleInitial {
    get {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(MiddleInitial) == true) {
            return MiddleInitial;

        }
        return $ "{MiddleInitial.Trim()}.";

    }
    set {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(MiddleInitial) == true) {
            return MiddleInitial;

        }
        return $ "{MiddleInitial.Trim()}.";
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to return if the value of the property is null? And, do you want to preserve the white spaces in the property?

Comment: empty string would be great I dont need to  preserve the white spaces in the property

Comment: Then just  apply the Trim at the Set accessor.

Comment: so I need it on both the get and set? I get error about set returns voids a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression.

Comment: you need to use a backing field when your property is not a simple `get; set;`

Comment: FYI in `if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(MiddleInitial) == true)` you don't need the `== true` part, it's usually omitted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an internal private backing field for the property allows you a fine control on what goes into the property and what you return back

```
// The blank value should be the default for the property
private string _middleInitial = "";

public string MiddleInitial 
{
    get { return _middleInitial; }

    // When someone tries to set a new value for the property
    // check for Invalid values (in this case a null ) and
    // reset the property back to the default 
    // (or even throw an exception if it is the case)
    set 
    { 
        _middleInitial = (value == null ? "" : value.Trim()); 
        // if(value == null)
        //    throw new ArgumentException("Null is not accepted");
        // else 
        //    _middleInitial = value.Trim();
    }
}
```

Comment: where would I add the `.`  after the `value.Trim()`

Comment: would it be something like this `_middleInitial = (value == null ? "" : value.Trim() + ".");`

Answer (score 1):

Inside your get method's if condition, you should check false, not true. Like below:

```
get
            {
                //if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(MiddleInitial) == true)
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(MiddleInitial) == false)
                {
                    return MiddleInitial;

                }
                return $"{MiddleInitial.Trim()}.";

            }
```